# Trouble creating a multipart/form-data POST request in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, multipartform-data, multipart, ktor, ktor-client

I'm trying to create a multipart/form-data POST request in Ktor using Kotlin, similar to an HTTP request I previously implemented using curl.

Here's the curl command for reference:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "[name]=[json content]" "[request url]"
```

In the above curl command, I'm creating a POST request with a multipart form data body. The form data has a single field `new_profile` that contains a serialized JSON string.

I'm having trouble replicating this in Ktor. Here's my current Kotlin code:

```kotlin
class MultiPartContent(val parts: List<Part>) : OutgoingContent.WriteChannelContent() {
    // val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    // val boundary = "***ktor-$uuid-ktor-${System.currentTimeMillis()}***"

    data class Part(
        val name: String,
        val filename: String? = null,
        val headers: Headers = Headers.Empty,
        val writer: suspend ByteWriteChannel.() -> Unit
    )

    override suspend fun writeTo(channel: ByteWriteChannel) {
        for (part in parts) {
            // channel.writeStringUtf8("--$boundary\r\n")
            val partHeaders = Headers.build {
                val fileNamePart = if (part.filename != null) "; filename=\"${part.filename}\"" else ""
                append("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"${part.name}\"$fileNamePart")
                appendAll(part.headers)
            }
            for ((key, value) in partHeaders.flattenEntries()) {
                channel.writeStringUtf8("$key: $value\r\n")
            }
            channel.writeStringUtf8("\r\n")
            part.writer(channel)
            channel.writeStringUtf8("\r\n")
        }
        // channel.writeStringUtf8("--$boundary--\r\n")
    }

    override val contentType = ContentType.MultiPart.FormData
        // .withParameter("boundary", boundary)
        .withCharset(Charsets.UTF_8)

    class Builder {
        val parts = arrayListOf<Part>()

        fun add(part: Part) {
            parts += part
        }

        fun add(
            name: String,
            filename: String? = null,
            contentType: ContentType? = null,
            headers: Headers = Headers.Empty,
            writer: suspend ByteWriteChannel.() -> Unit
        ) {
            val contentTypeHeaders: Headers =
                if (contentType != null) headersOf(HttpHeaders.ContentType, contentType.toString()) else headersOf()
            add(Part(name, filename, headers + contentTypeHeaders, writer))
        }

        fun add(name: String, text: String, contentType: ContentType? = null, filename: String? = null) {
            add(name, filename, contentType) { writeStringUtf8(text) }
        }

        fun add(
            name: String,
            data: ByteArray,
            contentType: ContentType? = ContentType.Application.OctetStream,
            filename: String? = null
        ) {
            add(name, filename, contentType) { writeFully(data) }
        }

        internal fun build(): MultiPartContent = MultiPartContent(parts.toList())
    }

    companion object {
        fun build(callback: Builder.() -> Unit) = Builder().apply(callback).build()
    }
}

operator fun Headers.plus(other: Headers): Headers = when {
    this.isEmpty() -> other
    other.isEmpty() -> this
    else -> Headers.build {
        appendAll(this@plus)
        appendAll(other)
    }
}

expect fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit = {}): HttpClient

class Client {
    private val client = httpClient()

    public suspend fun multiport(data: data): HttpStatusCode {
        val json: String =  Json.encodeToString(value = data)
        println(createMyProfileJson)
        val res = client.post("[url]") {
            contentType(ContentType.MultiPart.FormData)
            setBody(
                MultiPartContent.build {
                    add(name = "[name]", text = json, contentType = ContentType.Application.Json)
                }
            )
        }
        return res.status
    }
```

I'm getting this error when I run my code:

```
400 bad reqeust
```

Can someone guide me on how I can properly create this multipart/form-data POST request in Ktor, similar to the above curl command? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you replicate those Ktor parts if you can simply append a form field with JSON as String?

Answer (score 1):

```
        val res = client.post("[url]") {
            contentType(ContentType.MultiPart.FormData)
            setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(
                formData {
                    append("name", [data])
                }
            ))
        }
        return res.status
```